# Under ARC, are Blocks automatically copied when assigned to an ivar via the property?

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Assume

```
typedef void (^MyResponseHandler) (NSError *error);
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyResponseHandler ivarResponseHandler;
synthesize ivarResponseHandler = _ivarResponseHandler;

- (void)myMethod:(MyResponseHandler)responseHandler
{
    self.ivarResponseHandler = responseHandler;
    ...
}
```

Is the assignment to the ivar through the `@property` correct?  I know that in manual memory management you would have needed `self.ivarResponseHandler = [responseHandler copy];` to make sure the block was copied from the stack to the heap.  But watching Session 322 - Objective-C Advancements in Depth (minute 25) from WWDC 2011, the speaker says that ARC automatically handles the assignment of a block to an ivar. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bearMountain,

The easiest way to ensure the block is copied is to, in fact, set the `@property` to use copy. As in:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) MyResponseHandler ivarResponseHandler;
```

It does everything you need.

Andrew

Comment: Doesn't answer the question directly.  But I think I'll use this pattern in my code now.

Comment: (two years later) I've just asked very similar question which answers yours: [Should I still copy/Block_copy the blocks under ARC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334863). General conclusion of the answer there is that the form for writing properties for blocks, this accepted answer here has, is absolutely right and correct form even in present days.

Answer (score 11):

ARC **will** automatically perform the copy for you in the code you posted.

If you convert the block to an `id`, ARC will **not** perform the copy for you.  For example, in this code, ARC will not perform the copy because `addObject:`'s argument type is `id`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:responseHandler];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Answered my question and more.

Comment: @adonoho Is it true that [the block is not automatically copied if assigned directly to an ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453261/under-arc-are-blocks-automatically-copied-when-assigned-to-an-ivar-directly)?

Comment: bearMountain, I don't know what happens when it is assigned to an ivar. Frankly, I don't really want to depend upon what the compiler is going to do. I know that it is copied when assigned to a copy `@property`. I also know you can directly copy the block yourself on the assignment to the ivar. In both cases, there is no ambiguity. I prefer to always use `@property`s. Andrew