# Under ARC, are Blocks automatically copied when assigned to an ivar directly?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, ivar

Assume the following code under ARC,

```
typedef void (^MyResponseHandler) (NSError *error);
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    MyResponseHandler _ivarResponseHandler;
}

- (void)myMethod:(MyResponseHandler)responseHandler
{
    _ivarResponseHandler = responseHandler;
    ...
}
```

Question: Is the block automatically copied to the heap when assigned to the ivar?

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417851/under-arc-are-blocks-automatically-copied-when-assigned-to-an-ivar-via-the-prop) implied that it is copied when assigned through a `@property`.  But, today I used the above code and received an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` that was fixed by changing to

`_ivarResponseHandler = [responseHandler copy]`.

Answer (score 10):

Edit: My previous answer was likely wrong.

Some selected excerpts from the [ARC docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) say:

**3. Retainable object pointers**

A retainable object pointer (or retainable pointer) is a value of a retainable object pointer type (retainable type). There are three kinds of retainable object pointer types:

- block pointers (formed by applying the caret (^) declarator sigil to a function type)

**4.2. Semantics**

Assignment occurs when evaluating an assignment operator. The semantics vary based on the qualification:

- For __strong objects, the new pointee is first retained; second, the lvalue is loaded with primitive semantics; third, the new pointee is stored into the lvalue with primitive semantics; and finally, the old pointee is released. This is not performed atomically; external synchronization must be used to make this safe in the face of concurrent loads and stores.

**4.4.1. Objects**

If an object is declared with retainable object owner type, but without an explicit ownership qualifier, its type is implicitly adjusted to have __strong qualification.

**7.5. Blocks**

With the exception of retains done as part of initializing a __strong parameter variable or reading a __weak variable, whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a Block_copy. The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a call.

So I think the answer is *maybe*, depending on the optimizer.

Comment: Do you know that I am asking in reference to an Automatic Reference Counted environment?  It seems your foo/bar example wouldn't be a problem in ARC ...?

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Your answer, or the supplied apple documentation says nothing about whether ARC automatically moves a block to the heap when assigned to an instance variable.  It seems the answer to this question will have to come from the [clang Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.blocks).

Comment: Thanks for all the effort sbooth.  Wow, this doc is so hard to understand.  Actually, I would read it that the compiler -will- insert a Block_copy. It seems like an ivar defaults to __strong and thus the assignment would "call for retaining a value of block pointer type" and thus insert the Block_copy.  Thought it would be great to have a definitive answer, I think for now I'll settle for storing blocks in a `@property(copy)`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem and solution indicate that my answer to your other question was probably wrong. I based it on the last paragraph of section 7.5 of [the clang Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.blocks):

> With the exception of retains done as part of initializing a `__strong` parameter variable or reading a `__weak` variable, whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a `Block_copy`. The optimizer may remove such copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a call.

I took “these semantics” to mean the whole document, but if “these semantics” to refers to only section 7.5, then ARC only inserts a `Block_copy` for a block that is captured by a block.

Comment: I agree it isn't clear what "these semantics" is referring to

Comment: I spoke to the Apple engineer that wrote this section.  He said "these semantics" refers to the whole document.  Thus a `Block_copy` should be automatically inserted.  It seems that maybe this was a bug early on with blocks that was later fixed.